# Is this a lazy thread safe Generic multiton?

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns

Could somebody check if this version of a Generic Multiton is lazy and thread safe?

I coded it based on [Jon Skeet's version of a lazy thread safe Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx), on O'Reilly's C# Design Patterns, and on Wikipedia C# version of a Multiton.

```
public sealed class Multiton<T> where T : class, new() {
    private static readonly Dictionary<object, Lazy<T>> _instances = new Dictionary<object, Lazy<T>>();
    public static T GetInstance(object key) {
        Lazy<T> instance;
        if (!_instances.TryGetValue(key, out instance)) {
            instance = new Lazy<T>(() => new T());
            _instances.Add(key, instance);
        }
        return instance.Value;
    }
    private Multiton() {
    }
}
```

Comment: This should likely be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Isn't a mutliton just a singleton dictionary.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Why?  It's not asking for the best way to improve it; it's asking whether the code will work properly.

Comment: @Servy: He is asking for a *code review*.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth No, a code review would be pretty much saying, "so how's my code, what could be done to make it better", whereas this is asking about a specific, narrowly scoped, property of the program and an objective analysis as to whether or not that property exists.  Completely appropriate for SO.

Comment: @Servy: Still a code review he is requesting. But I will stop discussing with you right now. The past shows that once we two start discussing something, it goes on forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary class is not thread-safe, you can use ConcurrentDictionary to atomically check if element is in dictionary and add/get value from dictionary:

```
public sealed class Multiton<T> where T : class, new() {
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<object, Lazy<T>> _instances = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, Lazy<T>>();

    public static T GetInstance(object key) {
        Lazy<T> instance = _instances.GetOrAdd(key, k => new Lazy<T>(() => new T()));
        return instance.Value;
    }

    private Multiton() {
    }
}
```

Comment: It's important to note that using `Lazy<T>` is critical to this architecture as there is a small possibility that GetOrAdd may run its delegate more than once for the same key (but throw one of the values away). Using `Lazy<T>` guards against this issue because the only thing thrown away is a Lazy, not the T that you really want to singly instantiate.

Comment: @Rafael But the dictionary isn't constructed lazily, so, its not fully lazy, right.

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary` isn't designed to be accessed by multiple threads, and you aren't synchronizing access, so no, it won't always work as expected when accessed simultaneously.

The simplest solution is to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to the multiton concept and question its necessity. That said, you could improve on this considerably by using a `ConcurrentDictionary<T>` as follows:

```
public sealed class Multiton<T> where T : class, new() {
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<object, Lazy<T>> _instances = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<object, Lazy<T>>();
    public static T GetInstance(object key) {
        return _instances.GetOrAdd(key, k=>new Lazy<T>(() => new T())).Value;
    }
    private Multiton() {
    }
}
```

This is great because even though there's a chance of generating two `Lazy<T>`s on the same key if GetOrAdd is called concurrently, only one will get added/returned by GetOrAdd, meaning the cost of this parallel add is only a throwaway Lazy that hasn't had its value instantiated. This is why retaining `Lazy<T>` is critical to making this work properly. Take a read of [this](http://softwareblog.alcedo.com/post/2012/01/11/Sometimes-being-Lazy-is-a-good-thing.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) to make your dictionary thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

The access to the `Dictionnary` is not synchronized. You should lock it:

```
    public static T GetInstance(object key) {
        lock (_instances) {   
           Lazy<T> instance;
           if (!_instances.TryGetValue(key, out instance)) {
               instance = new Lazy<T>(() => new T());
               _instances.Add(key, instance);
           }
        }
        return instance.Value;
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't include accessing `instance.Value` inside of the lock.  It will already be properly sychronized, so it's not needed, and there's no need to prevent some other thread from accessing the dictionary while you are waiting to access the value of the `Lazy`.

Comment: I was trying to not use the locking mechanism using the Lazy type

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking , isn't this a more accuarate implementation of a thread safe Multiton, based on Jon Skeet's original lazy thread safe singleton?.

To be fully lazy, the static dictionary needs to be lazy, this is the analog for the original singleton. The dictionary members also need to be lazy to handle the [unlikey but possible double instantiation issue](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/01/16/concurrentdictionarytkeytvalue-used-with-lazyt/).

Here is a fully generic implementation I propose.

```
public sealed class Multiton<TKey, TInstance>
    where TInstance : class, new()
{
    private static readonly
        Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TInstance>>> dic =
            new Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TInstance>>>(
                () => new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TInstance>>());

    public static TInstance Instance(TKey key)
    {
        return dic.Value.GetOrAdd(
            key, 
            k => new Lazy<TInstance>(() => new TInstance())).Value;
    }

    private Multiton()
    {
    }
}
```